# .NET Code Contracts - ProjectA.exe cannot find ProjectB.Contracts.dll when both are in same solution

Tags: c#, msbuild, code-contracts

I have a C# solution in VS2013, with the Code Contracts extension installed.  In my solution I have an application project (ProjectA) and a class library project (ProjectB).  ProjectA references ProjectB, and most of ProjectB's public members have contracts associated with them.

I can access most of ProjectB's members from ProjectA without issue, but on one property I am getting a `FileNotFoundException`, with the message *"Could not load file or assembly 'ProjectB.Contracts, Version=....' or one of its dependencies."*

Here is what the fusion log has to say:

> === Pre-bind state information ===
>
> LOG: DisplayName = [SolutionName].ProjectB.Contracts, Version=1.0.5953.23121, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null  (Fully-specified)
>
> LOG: Appbase = [SolutionDir]/[SolutionName].ProjectA/bin/Debug/
>
> LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL Calling assembly : [SolutionName].ProjectC,  Version=1.0.5953.23122, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null.
>
> xxx
>
> LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
>
> LOG: Using application configuration file: [MyDocuments][SolutionName][SolutionName].ProjectA\bin\Debug[SolutionName].ProjectA.vshost.exe.config
>
> LOG: Using host configuration file:
>
> LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
>
> LOG: Policy not being applied to reference at this time (private, custom, partial, or location-based assembly bind).
>
> LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   [SolutionDir]/[SolutionName].ProjectA/bin/Debug/[SolutionName].ProjectB.Contracts.DLL.
>
> LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   [SolutionDir]/[SolutionName].ProjectA/bin/Debug/[SolutionName].ProjectB.Contracts/[SolutionName].ProjectB.Contracts.DLL.
>
> LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   [SolutionDir]/[SolutionName].ProjectA/bin/Debug/[SolutionName].ProjectB.Contracts.EXE.
>
> LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   [SolutionDir]/[SolutionName].ProjectA/bin/Debug/[SolutionName].ProjectB.Contracts/[SolutionName].ProjectB.Contracts.EXE.

The only references in this solution are standard Framework libraries, other projects in this solution, and one other first-party library (which only references System.dll).  I've tried cleaning and rebuilding all projects in this solution, as well as the other first-party library.

I am confused for several reasons.

1. In the output window, I can see that all of ProjectA and ProjectB's references (and their references) have already been loaded.
2. Other seemingly similar methods and properties with similar contracts are not causing any issues. Also, I've been using Code Contracts for months in several solutions and I haven't run into this yet.
3. Shouldn't the contract code already be recompiled into ProjectB.dll? Why does ProjectA even need to know that there is a .Contracts library?  (Other than for intellisense and static analysis)

Does anyone know what might be going on here?

---

**Edit:** All projects in solution are targeting .NET 4.0 and "Any CPU".

Comment: check they are all compiling against the same framework (e.g. .NET 4.5) and platform target (e.g. "Any CPU") in the project properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a few things I tried that didn't work:

On the project settings for ProjectA, on the Code Contracts tab, I tried adding *...ProjectB\bin\Debug\CodeContracts* to the field *Extra Contract Library Paths*.  This did not change anything.

I also tried manually adding a reference to ProjectB.Contacts.dll. This turned my `FileNotFoundException` into a `MissingMethodException`.  This made me think the issue was perhaps due to an error by the Code Contracts rewriter.  Enter [ILSpy](http://ilspy.net/).

---

The contract that was causing the issue was basically this in the original source code:

```
Contract.Requires<ArgumentNullException>(collection.All(x => x != null));
```

But I had put it in a contract abbreviator method like this:

```
public static class PreCondition {
    [ContractAbbreviator]
    public static void NotIsOrHasNull<T>(IEnumerable<T> collection){
        Contract.Requires<ArgumentNullException(collection != null,   
            "Collection cannot be null.");
        Contract.Requires<ArgumentNullException>(collection.All(x => x != null), 
            "Collection cannot contain null.");
    }
}
```

and called it in a class like this:

```
public class Class1{
    public void DoStuff(IEnumerable<T> collection){
        PreCondition.NotIsOrHasNull(collection);
        foreach (var x in collection){
            //Stuff
        }
    }
}
```

When viewing the troublesome method call in ILSpy, I saw it was trying to call an instance method named `Class1.NotIsOrHasNull`, instead of the static method `PreCondition.NotIsOrHasNull`.

---

**The Solution:**

I changed the `PreCondition` class to move the LINQ expression into its own `Pure` function, and change the contract abbreviator to call that method.

```
public static class PreCondition {

    [Pure]
    public static Boolean CollectionContainsNull(IEnumerable<T> collection){
        Contract.Requires<ArgumentNullException(collection != null);

        if (typeof(T).IsValueType)
            return false;

        return collection.Any(x => Object.Equals(x, null));
    }

    [ContractAbbreviator]
    public static void NotIsOrHasNull<T>(IEnumerable<T> collection){
        Contract.Requires<ArgumentNullException(collection != null,   
            "Collection cannot be null.");
        Contract.Requires<ArgumentNullException>(!CollectionContainsNull(collection)), 
            "Collection cannot contain null.");
    }
}
```

Now the method call in `Class1` works and the IL looks correct in ILSpy.

+1 to ILSpy!